# setInterval seems to speed up?

Tags: jquery, setinterval

I'm trying to design my own image slider you can see it here: http://nitrous-networks.co.uk/webdev/

I'm using setInterval to change the slides around, however I've noticed that when you click the slide navigation several times quickly once the animation has caught up the speed of the setInterval seems to change. By default it should be 8000millis, but by the time its going again its down to maybe 1000 for no reason.

here is a fiddle with the scroller code: http://jsfiddle.net/OwenMelbz/e7eEe/

**HTML  Markup:**

```
<!-- Slider Start -->
<div id="slider" class="">
    <div id="slide-wrap">
    <ul>
        <li>slide 1</li>
        <li>slide 2</li>
        <li>slide 3</li>
        <li>slide 4</li>
        <li>slide 5</li>
        <li>slide 6</li>
        <li>slide 7</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="slide-controller"></div>
    </div>
</div><!-- /slider -->​
```

**CSS**

```
#slide-wrap {
width:960px;
height:100%;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
}
#slider {
width:100%;
height:200px;
color: white;
background-color: #000;
background-image: url('http://nitrous-networks.co.uk/webdev/images/sliderbg.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center -200px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
position: relative;
}
#slider ul{
width:960px;
height:100%;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}
#slider ul li {
width:960px;
height:200px;
}
.slide-controller {
position: absolute;
left: 3px;
top: 50%;
height: 150px !important;
width:20px !important;
margin-top: -75px;
border-radius: 10px;
background-color: #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
background: rgb(22,22,22); /* Old browsers */
/* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
 background:     url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(22,22,22,1) 0%, rgba(13,13,13,1) 46%,     rgba(17,17,17,1) 50%, rgba(10,10,10,1) 53%, rgba(35,35,35,1) 76%, rgba(30,30,30,1) 87%, rgba(27,27,27,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(22,22,22,1)), color-stop(46%,rgba(13,13,13,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(17,17,17,1)), color-stop(53%,rgba(10,10,10,1)), color-stop(76%,rgba(35,35,35,1)), color-stop(87%,rgba(30,30,30,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(27,27,27,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(22,22,22,1) 0%,rgba(13,13,13,1) 46%,rgba(17,17,17,1) 50%,rgba(10,10,10,1) 53%,rgba(35,35,35,1) 76%,rgba(30,30,30,1) 87%,rgba(27,27,27,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(22,22,22,1) 0%,rgba(13,13,13,1) 46%,rgba(17,17,17,1) 50%,rgba(10,10,10,1) 53%,rgba(35,35,35,1) 76%,rgba(30,30,30,1) 87%,rgba(27,27,27,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(22,22,22,1) 0%,rgba(13,13,13,1) 46%,rgba(17,17,17,1) 50%,rgba(10,10,10,1) 53%,rgba(35,35,35,1) 76%,rgba(30,30,30,1) 87%,rgba(27,27,27,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
 background: linear-gradient(left,  rgba(22,22,22,1) 0%,rgba(13,13,13,1) 46%,rgba(17,17,17,1) 50%,rgba(10,10,10,1) 53%,rgba(35,35,35,1) 76%,rgba(30,30,30,1) 87%,rgba(27,27,27,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#161616', endColorstr='#1b1b1b',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-8 */
 }
.blip {width:10px;height:10px;border-radius:5px;margin: 0 auto;margin-top:10px;opacity:0.7;}
.blip:hover {opacity:1;cursor: pointer;}
.currentslide{opacity:1 !importantbackground: rgb(255,48,25); /* Old browsers */
/* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,48,25,1) 0%, rgba(207,4,4,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,48,25,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(207,4,4,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,48,25,1) 0%,rgba(207,4,4,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,48,25,1) 0%,rgba(207,4,4,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,48,25,1) 0%,rgba(207,4,4,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,48,25,1) 0%,rgba(207,4,4,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff3019', endColorstr='#cf0404',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-8 */
}
.inactiveslide{background: rgb(226,226,226); /* Old browsers */
/* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(226,226,226,1) 0%, rgba(219,219,219,1) 50%, rgba(209,209,209,1) 51%, rgba(254,254,254,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(226,226,226,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(219,219,219,1)), color-stop(51%,rgba(209,209,209,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(254,254,254,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(226,226,226,1) 0%,rgba(219,219,219,1) 50%,rgba(209,209,209,1) 51%,rgba(254,254,254,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(226,226,226,1) 0%,rgba(219,219,219,1) 50%,rgba(209,209,209,1) 51%,rgba(254,254,254,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(226,226,226,1) 0%,rgba(219,219,219,1) 50%,rgba(209,209,209,1) 51%,rgba(254,254,254,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(left,  rgba(226,226,226,1) 0%,rgba(219,219,219,1) 50%,rgba(209,209,209,1) 51%,rgba(254,254,254,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e2e2e2', endColorstr='#fefefe',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-8 */
}​
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//Setup Variables
var slidecount = 1;
var slidepos = 0;
var pos = ['-1', '-1', '199', '399', '599', '799', '999', '1199'];
var slideid = 2;
//var message = 'vars setup';
var Interval;

var slideSpeed = 8000; //Milliseconds 

// Turns Slider List Objects into the Controller blips & Applied Class's
$('#slider li').each(function() {
    $('.slide-controller').append('<div data-slide="' + slidecount + '" class="blip inactiveslide"></div>');
    $(this).attr('id', 'slide-' + slidecount);
    slidecount++;
    $('.blip:first').removeClass('inactiveslide').addClass('currentslide');
    //message = 'list setup';
    //console.log(message);
});

slidecount = 1;

// Change Slide Function


function ChangeSlide(e) {
    slidepos = pos[e];
    var bgshift = slidepos * -1;
    bgshift = bgshift / 2;
    //scrolls to position
    $('#slider ul').animate({
        scrollTop: slidepos
    }, 1000);
    $('#slider').animate({
        'background-position-y': bgshift
    }, 1500);
    //remove old active button
    $('.currentslide').removeClass('currentslide').addClass('inactiveslide');
    //changes active button
    $('.blip[data-slide=' + e + ']').removeClass('inactiveslide').addClass('currentslide');
    slidepos++;
    //message = 'changeslide run! vars: slidepos='+slidepos+'';
    var message = 'rotatetimer: ' + RotateTimer + ' Interval:' + Interval + ' speed:' + slideSpeed;
    console.log(message);

}

//Controller Function
$('.blip').live('click', function() {
    slideid = $(this).attr('data-slide');
    ChangeSlide(slideid);
    //message = 'clicked! slideid:'+slideid;
    //console.log(message);
    clearInterval(Interval);
    RotateTimer = setTimeout(GoGo, slideSpeed);
});

// Auto Rotate


function Rotate() {
    var currentslide = $('.currentslide').attr('data-slide');
    var nextslide = currentslide;
    nextslide++;
    if (nextslide == "8") {
        nextslide = 1;
    }
    ChangeSlide(nextslide);
    //message = 'Rotate Run! vars: currentslide='+currentslide+' nextid='+nextslide;
    //console.log(message);
}

//Starts The Auto Rotate and Runs it Every 8 Seconds


function GoGo() {
    Interval = setInterval(Rotate, slideSpeed);
}

//Triggers the Rotate After 3 Seconds
var RotateTimer = setTimeout(GoGo, slideSpeed);
//console.log(RotateTimer);
});​
```

Basically I'd like to know why it speeds up over time and a possible fix!

Thanks

Owen

Comment: Live links to other sites can be a useful *adjunct* to a question, but always put the relevant code/markup **in the question itself**. Why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Comment: sorry, its just there was lots of code, and I didnt want to flood the page

Comment: This is the point.  You should break the problem down into a smaller code sample so that others can read it and suggest a solution.  Otherwise everyone has to look through all of that code.

Comment: according to the console the speed is constant i.e 8000

Comment: FWIW, we really _don't_ need to see your CSS files to help debug a JS problem...

Comment: @ j4y well that is the "smaller code sample" thats the variables, and functions that are used to animate it. nothing else- but its still a lot of code

@3nigma that is what the speed is suposed to be, but when you try it out, it clearly isnt 8 seconds, its about half a second.

@ Alnitak my bad :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have clearTimeout and it's seems you miss some clearInterval too.

I think your setTimeout and the GoGo function is useless.

here's the corrected js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Setup Variables
    var slidecount = 1;
    var slidepos = 0;
    var pos = ['-1', '-1', '199', '399', '599', '799', '999', '1199'];
    var slideid = 2;
    //var message = 'vars setup';
    var Interval;

    var slideSpeed = 8000; //Milliseconds 

    // Turns Slider List Objects into the Controller blips & Applied Class's
    $('#slider li').each(function() {
        $('.slide-controller').append('<div data-slide="' + slidecount + '" class="blip inactiveslide"></div>');
        $(this).attr('id', 'slide-' + slidecount);
        slidecount++;
        $('.blip:first').removeClass('inactiveslide').addClass('currentslide');
        //message = 'list setup';
        //console.log(message);
    });

    slidecount = 1;

    // Change Slide Function


    function ChangeSlide(e) {
        slidepos = pos[e];
        var bgshift = slidepos * -1;
        bgshift = bgshift / 2;
        //scrolls to position
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            scrollTop: slidepos
        }, 1000);
        $('#slider').animate({
            'background-position-y': bgshift
        }, 1500);
        //remove old active button
        $('.currentslide').removeClass('currentslide').addClass('inactiveslide');
        //changes active button
        $('.blip[data-slide=' + e + ']').removeClass('inactiveslide').addClass('currentslide');
        slidepos++;
        //message = 'changeslide run! vars: slidepos='+slidepos+'';
        var message = 'rotatetimer: ' + RotateTimer + ' Interval:' + Interval + ' speed:' + slideSpeed;
        console.log(message);

    }

    //Controller Function
    $('.blip').live('click', function() {
        clearInterval(Interval);
        Interval = setInterval(Rotate, slideSpeed);
        slideid = $(this).attr('data-slide');
        ChangeSlide(slideid);
        //message = 'clicked! slideid:'+slideid;
        //console.log(message);

    });

    // Auto Rotate


    function Rotate() {
        var currentslide = $('.currentslide').attr('data-slide');
        var nextslide = currentslide;
        nextslide++;
        if (nextslide == "8") {
            nextslide = 1;
        }
        ChangeSlide(nextslide);
        //message = 'Rotate Run! vars: currentslide='+currentslide+' nextid='+nextslide;
        //console.log(message);
    }

    //Starts The Auto Rotate and Runs it Every 8 Seconds

    //Triggers the Rotate After 3 Seconds
   // var RotateTimer = setTimeout(GoGo, slideSpeed);
    //console.log(RotateTimer);

Interval = setInterval(Rotate, slideSpeed);
```

Comment: ah works a charm thanks, but what exactly did you do, Im failing to spot it!

Comment: Look the block after //Controller Function. I ensure that no Interval is running before setting a new one when the user click. And, like i said, i remove the GoGo function.